# Extracting temporal series data from netCDF4 using xarray and for loop

Tags: python, netcdf, for-loop

I have a netCDF4 file (see print output)

```
import xarray as xr


ds = xr.open_dataset("../Desktop/ERA/moisture/humidity.nc", engine = "netcdf4")
print(ds)

<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (longitude: 284, latitude: 107, time: 6574)
Coordinates:
  * longitude  (longitude) float32 -95.0 -94.75 -94.5 ... -24.75 -24.5 -24.25
  * latitude   (latitude) float32 -9.74 -9.99 -10.24 ... -35.74 -35.99 -36.24
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 2001-01-01T06:00:00 ... 2018-12-31T06:00:00
Data variables:
    r          (time, latitude, longitude) float32 75.06 75.04 ... 85.13 86.0
Attributes:
    Conventions:  CF-1.6
    history:      2021-10-01 13:44:47 GMT by grib_to_netcdf-2.20.0: /opt/ecmw...

# Define variables

lon = ds.longitude.data
lat = ds.latitude.data
rh = ds.r.data / 100
```

So I'm just trying to extract the relative humidity `r` data and write those in several txt files. Each txt file is a pixel that contains a time series of `r` from 01/01/2001 until 12/31/2018. I have a total of 30281 pixels, therefore I should get 30281 txt files.

```
# Loop through each file inside the netCDF4 and create .txt SWAT+ files

k=0 # K number of days + steps 
i=0 # i height of line/vertical
j=0 # J width of the column
n=0 # n number of txt

for i in range(0,107): # The range corresponds at the number of rows (i) and columns (j)

    # This will create each txt file 
    
    for j in range(0,283):
        a = k # a is Z-axis time step (time/days/steps)
        n = n+1
        d = "ERArh%s.txt" %n # d is the name of the txt file. 
        file = open(d,"a") 
        file.write("20010101"+"\n") # date line
        file.close()
        
        # This will transfer the data from the netCDF4 file to the txt files created above

        
        for k in range(0,6573):
            humidity_C = min(rh[a][i][j], rh[a+1][i][j])
            min_C = "{0:.8f}".format(humidity_C) 
            a = k+1 
            d = "ERArh%s.txt" %n # string
            file = open(d,"a")
            file.write(min_C+"\n")
            file.close() 
            if a >= 6573: # value of each pixel, time 
                break
```

The problems I'm facing are:

Data does not match with the dates, so the extraction is wrong.
The date range is not complete, I get the data until the 12/30/2018 and I should get until the 12/31/2018.
I think that the problem might be the k value in the for k in range(0,6573): loop but I'm not sure.

How can I solve these issues ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured the problem.

1. `for i in range(0,107):`, `for j in range(0, 283):` and `for k in range(0, 6573):` are incorrect, because python will not include those lasts rows and columns at the moment of the extraction. So the correct way will be `for k in range(0, rh.shape[0]):` and the others `(0, rh.shape[1])` and `(0, rh.shape[2])`.
2. k was the problem, first as I didn't need a step (because I have only one data per day) I didn't include `a = k` in the `for j in range(0,rh.shape[2]):`, and redefine in the `for k in range(0,rh.shape[0]):` as `a = k`.
   So the loop will be something like this:

```
# Loop through each file inside the netCDF4 and create .txt SWAT+ files

k=0 # K number of days + steps 
i=0 # i height of line/vertical
j=0 # J width of the column
n=0 # n number of txt

for i in range(0,rh.shape[1]):
    
    # This will create each txt file 
    
    for j in range(0,rh.shape[2]):
        n = n+1
        d = "ERArh%s.txt" %n # d is the name of the txt file. 
        file = open(d,"a") 
        file.write("20010101"+"\n") # date line
        file.close()
        
        # This will transfer the data from the netCDF4 file to the txt files created above
        
        for k in range(0,rh.shape[0]):
            a = k
            humidity_C = rh[a][i][j]
            min_C = "{0:.8f}".format(humidity_C) # returns a string. To float it, wrap it up with "float()" # 8 decimal places
            d = "ERArh%s.txt" %n # string
            file = open(d,"a")
            file.write(min_C+"\n")
            file.close() 
            if a >= 6573: # value of each pixel, time (data.variables['time'].size)
                break
```